# How can I shortcut the color #F4F4F4?

Tags: css

I'm already using shortcuts for example #EEEEEE changed to #EEE

Is there any way that I can shortcut colors such as F4F4F4 using CSS

Hope someone has the answer

Comment: F4F4F4 is pretty close to F5F5F5, for which you might use the CSS color name "WhiteSmoke."  However, I expect the real answer to this is going to be "No. No you can't."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.
`F4F4F4` is shorter than `RGB(244,244,244)`, if it's any consolation `:)`

Answer (score 5):

No.

As you noted, colors on the form #xxyyzz can be shortened to #xyz, but there is no shorthand notation for colors where the red, green and blue components are all equal.

Comment: in his equation x = red, y = green, z = blue

Answer (score 1):

No you cant, only colors where the hex represntatino of each color (RGB) consits of to equal characters can be shortened.

read about it here http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/hex/

there are also names for certain colors (red, blue, lightblue,etc). pretty much actually, but i dont think your color is among them. read about that here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colornames.asp